# Use krb5 API to find KDC for a realm

Tags: c++, hadoop, kerberos

I am developing a kerberized application in C++ which makes use of the krb5 library. It is also intended to support multi realm kerberos, so the service it self runs in a realm such as `HADOOP.COM` and users are connecting from realm `USERS.COM`. For a tangential purpose, I need to know the KDC of the `USERS.COM` realm. I know the info is in the "realms" section of krb5.conf, but I need to be able to look this up programmatically.

So the problem is, given a realm, is there a way to look up the associated KDC using just the krb5 API (i.e. not manually parsing the krb5.conf file)

The API I am referencing is documented [here](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-current/doc/appldev/refs/api/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no public API to do this.  The `k5_locate_kdc` function (in the MIT implementation; Heimdal approaches somewhat differently) is an internal function.  To make things more complicated, there are several ways a KDC can be located:

- krb5.conf
- DNS SRV records
- other KDC location plugins